# Data bigger than bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm writing data automatically into a modal, but as you can see [(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgZe1.png) i'm having a size problem.

```
<div id="check-answers" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Answers</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata</p>
                <p>datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata</p>
                <p>datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how would i fix this so it can fit any kind of data?

Comment: add a class to modal and write css rules that size it the way you need. Can see all the relevant current css in browser dev tools elements inspector

Comment: Also learn about css word wrapping and overflow rules

Comment: can you please provide a link where i can find all that things?

Comment: google...really need a link to get there?

Comment: I knew that answer is coming, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this to your css

```
.modal-body p {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[working example](https://codepen.io/xploshioOn/pen/BRLaQP)

Comment: if i change the "p" with "h3" or any other thing, that would still works?